# .htaccess RewriteRule returning 404 unexpectedly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Rewriting is working using this htaccess file, but for some reason this new rule I created doesn't seem to be working. Here is the new rule:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(webapps|gamedev|digitalart)$ $1/index.php [NC,PT,L]`

Here is my entire set of rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(webapps|gamedev|digitalart)$ $1/index.php [NC,PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The public URL that this .htaccess is contained in is here:

`https://dustinhendricks.com/test`

The url I am testing is here:

`https://dustinhendricks.com/test/gamedev`

I expect the above URL to navigate (without changing the URL in browser) to here:

`https://dustinhendricks.com/test/index.php`

Instead it is returning a 404 error. Any ideas as to why this rewrite isn't working as expected? Tested it here, but seems to rewrite fine in this site [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=9cfaf593-47cb-40a6-a07e-0a468868bdd1)

Comment: is this .htaccess inside `test/` subdirectory?

Comment: @anubhava yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your .htaccess this way:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# add .php if there is a matching .php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# rewrite these paths to index.php
RewriteRule ^(webapps|gamedev|digitalart)/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Note that your .htaccess is already inside `test/` subdirectory, hence matched pattern in `RewriteRule` will be relative to `test/` subdirectory.

Comment: I copy pasted. Still getting a 404. the other two rewrites still work. `test/index` works, `test/index.php` works. `test/webapps` fails

Comment: never mind, something went wrong during upload. Your solution does work. Thank you!

Comment: although now http://dustinhendricks.com/index does not switch it to https

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in first `https` rule. Please test it now.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but this is now directing blank paths to an internal path, like dustinhendricks.com/test/ redirects to https://dustinhendricks.com/internal/file/path/test/index

Comment: Can you change last rule to `RewriteRule ^(webapps|gamedev|digitalart)?/?$ index.php [NC,L]` and retest

Comment: retested. still the same. it's something outside of that line, because removing the entire last rule results in the same strange path for `/test/`

Comment: i've removed all rules. still same result. i think my server admin must have changed something that broke this...

Comment: You can also try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` but you're right problem is something beyond this htaccess